# How to make child class use parent's default values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have a parent class:

```py
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar=10):
        self.foo = foo
```

And an inherited class from it:

```py
class InheritedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, x, y, bar=10):
        super().__init__(True, bar=bar)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

At the moment, `bar` has a default value in both the parent and the inherited class, which I have to keep track of to make sure they are both synced. How can I change the `InheritedClass` constructor to instead use the default value for `bar` defined in the `BaseClass`?

---

I've tried:

```py
class InheritedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, x, y, bar=None):
        if bar is None:
            super().__init__(True)
        else:
            super().__init__(True,bar)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

which provides the behavior I'm looking for, but doesn't seem very scalable. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't expose the parent's arguments at all in the signature; just pass what you receive on (if anything) on to the next class in the MRO.

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar=10, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # Do something with bar
        self.foo = foo


class InheritedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, x, y, **kwargs)
        kwargs['foo'] = True
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

You have to accept and pass on arbitrary keywords anyway to use `super` properly, so you may as well do the same thing for the parent class's arguments, even though you "know" them already.

This also means *always* using keyword arguments for `__init__`, as you can't really predict how your class's positional arguments will interact with another class on the MRO. (Positional arguments can only be consumed on a first-come, first-served basis, and you simply don't know in the case of multiple inheritance *when* your class's method will be called.)

```
foo = InheritedClass(bar=9, x=3, y=10)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, chepner. Very clear, with the minor exception of the last paragraph. I'm not very familiar with the context you're describing. Could you maybe elaborate a bit more?

Comment: See [Python's `super()` considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), particularly the section on practical advice.

Comment: In general, just because your base class only inherits from `object` doesn't mean it will always be the last class in some *other* class's MRO.

Comment: Thanks again, chepner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable arguments instead:

```
class InheritedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(True, *args, **kwargs)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not bad and yes there is a better way to do it maybe better than mine but here is what I come up with hope this helps.

**Sample:**

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar=10):
        self.foo = foo 
        self.bar = bar 

class InheritedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, x, y, bar=None):
        super().__init__(True, bar=bar)
        if bar is None: bar = self.bar
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```